# Flutter google map custom marker with gesture detector

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Now I am using google_maps_flutter to build my map, but it only has onTap function in Marker, how can I implement another gesture, like long press or tap down etc.

```
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('1'),
        position: LatLng(25.032970, 121.565415),
        icon: await getMarkerIcon("imageUrl", Size(120.0, 120.0)),
        consumeTapEvents: true,
        onTap: () {
          print('onPress');
        },
        onLongPress?
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapDescriptor customIcon;

// make sure to initialize before map loading
BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(size: Size(12, 12)),
        'assets/images/car-icon.png')
    .then((d) {
  customIcon = d;
});

final nearbyCarsLocation = [
  LatLng(24.9286825, 67.0403249),
  LatLng(24.985577, 67.0661056), //24.9294892,67.0391903,18.73z
];

void _getNearByCars() {

  for (var i = 0; i < nearbyCarsLocation.length; i++) {
    var now = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    _markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(nearbyCarsLocation[i].toString() + now.toString()),
      position: nearbyCarsLocation[i],
      // infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: address, snippet: "go here"),
      icon: customIcon ));
  }
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Hope this will help in getting custom nearby localities

Comment: I am not asking for how to make custom icon, but how to add gesture detect to the icon.